# Variation of Egoroff's theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space with a (positive) measure.

Let $\{f_n : X \to \mathbb{R} : n =1 ,2,...\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions satisfy the following properties :

1. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ , $f_n$ satisfies $|f_n|\leq g $ where $g\in L^1(X,\mu)$.
2. $f_n$ converges to a measurable function $f$ almost every where on $X$.

Then, For any given ${\epsilon}$ , there exists a measurable subset $E$ of $X$ such that $\mu (E) < \epsilon$ , and $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $X - E$.

Comment: This follows in a few lines from Egoroff. Saying you want to prove it _without_ Egoroff doesn't make much sense to me - it's (almost) like saying you want to show every integer has a unique prime factorization without the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, or you want to prove that every complex polynomial has a zero without the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. I mean it seems clear that a proof without Egoroff is going to just _contain_ the _proof_ of Egoroff. ???

Comment: I know you say. Ok. I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of at least two ways to prove this from Egoroff's Theorem, one straightforward but taking sort of several lines, one a "one-line" trick.

**Hint For One Proof:** If $\delta>0$ then $$\mu(\{x:g(x)\ge\delta\})<\infty.$$

**Hint For Another Proof:** If you define $\nu(E)=\int_E g\,d\mu$ then $\nu$ is a finite measure.

Comment: For the first proof, it is clear that you want to apply Egoroff's theorem to $\{x : g(x) \geq \delta\}$, yet could you provide a hint for what to do with the complement of that set?

Comment: @StevenHarding If $\delta$ is small enough then $|f-f_n|<\epsilon$ on the complement.

Comment: Could you post the proof?